# Are there off-the-shelf solutions/services for receiving events from smart contracts on the server?

Tags: blockchain, events, synchronization, event-handling

am working on a project where I need to catch events from smart contracts on the backend. Are there any solutions or services that help to catch events and pass them to the backend?

The main requirement is fault tolerance. The event must always be delivered to the server. If the backend is not available, they must be delivered when the work of the backend is restored.

I was considering moralis.io which has a functionality for catching events from contracts. But there are some questions about its fault tolerance.

Who has faced with such a task? Are there any ready made solutions? Or may be I have to develop them myself?

Answer (score 0):

> am working on a project where I need to catch events from smart contracts on the backend. Are there any solutions or services that help to catch events and pass them to the backend?

- Preferably [Run your local node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) for the maximum fault tolerance
- Use [web3.py for reading events](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) from the node
- The reader can resume reading events based on the last block number
- [An example resumable event reader implementation](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps.py)